# render object with map() and JSX - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, jsx

I have an object:

```
const data = {
  1: "apples",
  2: "bananas",
  3: "cherries"
}
```

I want to run through this items  and use them in rendering JSX. If it was typical array I would use map() but now it gives me an error :

```
"Property 'map' doesnot exists..."
```

what can I do in this case? thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is giving you that error since map() method can only be run on arrays and data is an object.

Rather change your code to

```
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => console.log(key, value))
```

For fetching only the keys

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => console.log(key))
```

For fetching only the values

```
Object.values(data).map(value => console.log(value))
```

Comment: Does this return data sorted by keys in ascending order? How can I keep order which I have specified in objec. ex. if I have const data ` { 3 : "apples", 1: "bananas", 2: "cherries" }` I want to keep 3, 1, 2 order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order , i hope this link will answer your question

Answer (score 1):

```
for (const key in data) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${data[key]}`);
}
```

good to know

`Object.keys(data)` will get you array of keys -> ['1', '2', '3']

`Object.values(data)`will get you array of values -> ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries']

Answer (score 0):

**You could consider using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to turn an object into an array before mapping it to UI**

```js
const data = {
  1: "apples",
  2: "bananas",
  3: "cherries"
}

console.log(Object.values(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.entries`

```js
return (
        <div>
            {
                Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
                    <p>{key}: {value}</p>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Does this return data sorted by keys in ascending order? How can I keep order which I have specified in objec. ex. if I have const data 
` { 3 : "apples", 1: "bananas", 2: "cherries" }`   
I want to keep 3, 1, 2 order

Comment: I think object in js are sorted by default. if you are reading from json file it will automatically sort the value when you load it if the json is an Object(dictionary like object)

{ .... }

Comment: Is there any other alternatives to keep key value pairs? as long as I want to keep specific order of keys when I iterate over them

Comment: Map are garanteed to keep order of insertion but idk how you are going to achieve that when you load from json. But the best way to achieve it is giving the order in the data and that would actually better because you can sort it using that key.

Comment: actually I'm not loading it from Json, data object  is hardcoded in code and I'm just looking if there is any other way to keep key value pairs and to maintain the ordering while iterating over it

Comment: in that case you can use Map like this

```const second = new Map([
  [1, "apples"],
  [2, 'bananas",']
])
``` 
it will preserve the order